# SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement while trying to delete from db

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to solve a problem with statement deletion query. Now the implementation looks like this.

```
 @Transactional
public void deleteStatements(LocalDate expiryDate) {
    int deletedStatements = statementRepository.deleteByIdCreatedDateBefore(expiryDate);
    logger.info("Deleted {} statements.", deletedStatements);
}


@Query(value = "WITH deleted AS (DELETE FROM generated_statements WHERE created_date < :expiryDate RETURNING id) " +
        "SELECT count(*) FROM deleted;", nativeQuery = true)
int deleteByIdCreatedDateBefore(LocalDate expiryDate);
```

Now I'm getting this error:
`could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement`

I tried adding @Modifying annotation, then I tried removing it, tried with various combinations of @Transactional and @Modifying, still got various errors regarding this deletion like:
`could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet` or `Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`
Now I'm really not sure what is the problem here.

Comment: Why do you need the `CTE` at all? JDBC will automatically return the number of deleted rows and I would expect that an obfuscation layer like JPA can actually return that information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, didn't quite understand what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your delete query with this

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM generated_statements WHERE created_date < :expiryDate", nativeQuery = true)
int deleteByIdCreatedDateBefore(LocalDate expiryDate);
```

or turn it directly into a JPQL/HQL query. No need for a nativeQuery. Example:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM GeneratedStatement g WHERE g.createDate < :expiryDate")
int deleteByIdCreatedDateBefore(LocalDate expiryDate);
```

By specifying an `int` return value, you will automatically get the number of deleted rows.

Comment: And what about annotations, which one should I use, @Modifying, @Transational?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to add \@Modifying on the queries and I updated my answer accordingly. But: You also need to execute your methods inside a \@Transaction. Typically your repository would be called from a service method, and you'd make that \@Transactional, you can however also make your repository methods \@Transactional, too.

Comment: And with @Modifying wouldn't I get a `could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet` exception because @Modifying can't return `ResultSet`? Because I got this error before because of this.

Comment: So I could just leave the @Transactional annotation on the method that calls the statementRepository method, as it is in my question, yes?

Comment: As for your second question (\@transactional), yes. For the first one: Try having \@Query, \@Modify and try it without a native query for now. It should actually work

Comment: Sorry, could you explain why native query is not needed in this case? (I'm trying the first solution you provided)

Comment: Well, I assume you are using Spring Data JPA, so you can simply use JQPL/HQL, which would be its appropriate query language.  If all you want to do is write "nativeQueries", you might want to have a look at Spring Data JDBC instead.

Comment: Ok, got it. I'm a bit unfamiliar with the JQPL/HQL, so could you please help figuring out how would my query look if `GeneratedStatement` consists from `GeneratedStatementId` object which has `created_date` in it, I doubt it would be as in your example just `g.created_date`

Comment: Could you post the full GeneratedStatement class? including the id. so we don't waste too much time :D

Answer (score 0):

Considering all this complex logic is to get number of deleted rows you can try just:

```java
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM generated_statements WHERE created_date < :expiryDate")
int deleteByIdCreatedDateBefore(LocalDate expiryDate);
```

or just using keywords(if your entity has createdDate attribute)

```
int deleteByCreatedDateBefore(LocalDate expiryDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM generated_statements WHERE created_date < ?1", nativeQuery = true)
int deleteByIdCreatedDateBefore(LocalDate expiryDate);
```

Comment: Try adding more details, please.